# Is any subset of the open ordinal space $[0,\Omega)$ $G_\delta$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, ordinals

Consider the open ordinal space $[0,\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the first uncountable ordinal.
Can I say that every subset of $[0,\Omega)$ is $G_\delta$? If yes, does this imply that $[0,\Omega)$ is perfectly normal?

Thank you!

---

so, which version is the right one..
[image]

Comment: No. See http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/the-first-uncountable-ordinal/ ... property **C**.

Comment: Strange. because I have just looked in "counterexamples in topology" and it is written there that $[0,\Omega)$ is perfectly normal.. I will add a picture bellow.. So, which one is the right one?

Comment: It does *not* say that $[0,\Omega)$ is perfectly normal (in the excerpt you posted). As pointed out in the link martini provided, the set of countable limit ordinals is a closed subset of $[0,\Omega)$ which is not $G_\delta$.

Comment: got it. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Note that [this link](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/the-first-uncountable-ordinal/), that @martini provided in the comments, shows that $[0,\Omega)$ is not perfectly normal (the countable limit ordinals are a closed subset of $[0, \Omega)$ that is not a $G_\delta$, as shown there by using the pressing down lemma.

The remarks from Counterexamples in Topology, e.g. item 5 in the posted picture, says that $[0, \Gamma)$ **for $\Gamma < \Omega$** (!) is second countable (and thus perfectly normal etc.) **Not** for $\Gamma = \Omega$, as we saw above. So you misread what item 5. says.

Being an order topology, $[0, \Omega)$ is completely normal, which is also known as hereditarily normal: every subspace is normal, or equivalently, every two separated sets $A$ and $B$ (i.e. the closure of $A$ misses $B$ and vice versa) have disjoint open neighbourhoods.